# How to control image resolution in ColorQuantize?

Tags: export, image, animation

When exporting a GIF animation, for example

```
listofgraphics = Table[Plot[Sin[x + a], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 10, 1}];
Export["mtest.gif", listofgraphics, ImageResolution -> 200]
```

to make the GIF file size smaller, we can reduce the number of colors first, maybe by using `ColorQuantize`. But I found that using `ColorQuantize` directly reduces image resolution, e.g.

```
ColorQuantize[#, 16] &[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}]]
```

gives

[image: rough image]

The image is quite rough.

So is it possible to control image resolution in `ColorQuantize`, or is there any better way to reduce color when exporting to GIF (the docs seem to not give an option to reduce color in `Export`)?

Comment: What does `ColorQuantize[Rasterize[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}]], 16]` produce for you?

Comment: @J.M. Oh, good! Thank you very much! I can set ImageResolution inside Rasterize

Comment: You need to remember that `ColorQuantize[]` expects an *image* as an argument, so if you feed it something that isn't an image, some conversions that may not be to your liking are done.

Comment: @J.M.needshelp. I see. Thank you : )

Answer (score 3):

To settle this:

As noted in the comments, the right way to go about this is to preprocess the plot first with `Rasterize[]`, before passing it to `ColorQuantize[]`. Witness the following:

```
plt = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, π/2}];
```

Compare

```
ColorQuantize[plt, 16]
```

[image: without rasterization]

with

```
ColorQuantize[Rasterize[plt, "Image"], 16]
```

[image: with rasterization]